# how to cleanly shutdown high-concurrency Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

When I try to shutdown my spring-integration process, the flow using an inbound Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter throws the following error message:

"org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Rejecting received message because of the listener container been stopeed in the meantime"

my inbound adapter is defined as follows:

```
Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
    Jms.container(jmsConnectionFactory, destinationName)
    .concurrency(highConcurrency)
    .get()
    )
```

I believe that my problem is that the default "receiveTimeout" on my jms container is too small and that I need to increase that value to cater for my "high-concurrency" (right ?), as "receiveTimeout" seems to be the only value the container "doShutdown" method cares about.
Now, the sourceCode for the receiveTimeout property says "this value needs to be smaller than the transaction timeout". Also the spring-integration doco regarding inbound jms adapters says "if you want the entire flow to be transactional [...] consider using a jms-message-driven-channel-adapter with acknowledge set to transacted (the default)", which seems to imply that the jms adapter is transactional by default.
Hence, my main question is: even though I'm not using any explicit transaction manager, do I need to not only explicitely set "receiveTimeout" on my container but also "transactionTimeout" with transactionTimeout > receiveTimeout ?
Thanks a lot in advance for your expertise and your time.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not "throws". That is just warn:

```
protected void doExecuteListener(Session session, Message message) throws JMSException {
    if (!isAcceptMessagesWhileStopping() && !isRunning()) {
        if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
            logger.warn("Rejecting received message because of the listener container " +
                    "having been stopped in the meantime: " + message);
        }
        rollbackIfNecessary(session);
        throw new MessageRejectedWhileStoppingException();
    }
```

And pay attention to that `rollbackIfNecessary(session);`. So, even if the received message slips somehow into this listener function, the whole environment makes it sure that the state is not broken and the data is not lost - the session is rolled back.

The `transactionTimeout` does not make sense if you don't use a `transactionManager`. Spring Integration makes it `transacted` exactly for the use-case we see around that warn log.